# Exercise 6(a) (b) Chapter 1, Rudin's PMA: verification

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am working through some of the exercises in Chapter 1 of Rudin's PMA, and would like to get some second thoughts on what I have written to make sure I am doing these exercises properly.

Fix $b>1$.

(a) If $m,n,p,q$ are integers, $n>0, q>0$, and $r = m/n = p/q$, prove that:
$$(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
Hence it makes sense to define $b^r = (b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Since $\frac{m}{n}= \frac{p}{q}$, we have $mq = pn$. It follows that
$$b^{mq} = b^{pn}$$
Observe:
\begin{align*}
(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^m)^{1 \cdot \frac{1}{n}} =(b^m)^{q \cdot \frac{1}{q} \cdot \frac{1}{n}}= (b^{mq})^{\frac{1}{q}\cdot \frac{1}{n}} = (b^{pn})^{\frac{1}{q}\cdot \frac{1}{n}}  = (b^{p})^{n \cdot \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{q}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}
\end{align*}

Can we rearrange the order of the exponents given what we've seen in the first chapter so far? I could not find anything about this, and I am not sure how I would justify it.

(b) Prove that $b^{r+s} = b^r b^s$ if $r$ and $s$ are rational.

Since $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$ write $r = \frac{e}{f}$ and $s = \frac{c}{d}$ for some integers $e,f,c,d$ with nonzero $f,d$. Then
\begin{align*}
b^{r+s} = b^{\frac{e}{f} + \frac{c}{d}} = b^{\frac{ed+fc}{fd}} = (b^{ed+fc})^{\frac{1}{fd}} = (b^{ed}b^{fc})^\frac{1}{fd} = b^{\frac{ed}{fd}}b^{\frac{fc}{fd}} = b^\frac{e}{f}b^\frac{c}{d} = b^r b^s
\end{align*}

Since $ed+fc$ is an integer, we may break it up as in the chain of equalities above. We use the Corollary to Theorem 1.21 for the step $(b^{ed}b^{fc})^\frac{1}{fd} = b^{\frac{ed}{fd}}b^{\frac{fc}{fd}}$.

Comment: Instead of rearranging(assuming law of exponent for rationals), you can check that $(b^m)^{1/n}$ and $(b^p)^{1/q}$ are equal when $nq$-powered(which can be justified by law of exponents for integers and definition of radicals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with roots, work with integer powers as much as possible.
You've already observed that $mq=pn$.  Note that $$((b^m)^{\frac 1n})^{nq}=b^{mq}=b^{pn}=((b^p)^{\frac 1q})^{qn}=((b^p)^{\frac 1q})^{nq},$$ and since $nq \in \Bbb Z$, exponentiation by $nq$ is $1$-$1$, from which it follows that $(b^m)^{\frac 1n}=(b^p)^{\frac 1q}$.

Similarly, for part b, raise both sides to an appropriate integer power ($fd$ appears suitable), prove equality there, and as above, use the fact that exponentiation by an integer is $1$-$1$ to conclude that the original expressions were equal.

Comment: One thing I'm wondering about is how we justify that operations "in the exponent" follow the same rules as in the field. For instance, in the chain of equality that is suggested, we also have some notion of associative property (to get (1/n)*n = 1). What is the complication when working with roots?

Comment: When $n$ is an integer, the definition of $b^{\frac 1n}$ is the number that, when raised to the $n$th power, results in $b$.  So you don't need an associative property.  You're relying on the definition of $n$th root.  You can take for granted (or easily prove) a lot of things when working with integer powers, and then (as we're doing here) bootstrap those properties to show they also work for rational powers and eventually for real powers.  For example, I am relying on the fact that, for  $m, q \in \Bbb Z, (b^m)^q=b^{mq}$.